# Difficulties in a proof by mathematical induction (2)

Tags: induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [proof by induction: n/(n+1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11831/proof-by-induction-n-n1)

Continuing from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134922/16797), I got a splendid answer that helped a lot. I'm tackling one now, but I've run into problems.

Prove by mathematical induction that

$$
\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{n}{n+1}
$$

Since I'm not all that conversant with Tex. . . I got to . . .

$$
\frac{2}{n(n+2)}
$$

How I got there is through fractional addition, expanding then factoring. I'm stuck now. 
Thanks. I would prefer simple answers.

Comment: Did you read through Bill's answer there about Telescopy and its usefulness? This one does not require induction if you knew the technique of telescopy.

Comment: @KannappanSampath That is too advanced. It's not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: That is not too advanced at all. In fact, you have written what the OP wrote out in a long form. The 3 answers there are, explain what you'd do in the form of hints. They should suffice if you mock what Asaf wrote out more explicitly in [his answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/134922/21436) to your last question.

Comment: I don't know where you got 2/(n(n+2)) from. Inductive step should be: Assume the sum from r=1 to n does equal n/(n+1). Then the sum from r=1 to n+1 equals (sum from r=1 to n) + 1/((n+1)(n+2)) = n/(n+1) + 1/((n+1)(n+2)) = ... (try and fill in the rest)

Comment: I think you made some arithmetic error. Maybe you can post your train of thought?

Comment: Thanks @AdamRubinson I'm currently on it.

Comment: Ahh! Found the error. Would get back to Adam and @sdcvvc.

Comment: Yeah. Got to (n+1)/(n+2)

Comment: Thanks everyone who contributed positively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ By [telescopic induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134925/242) the proof reduces to the elementary school calculation

$$\rm F(n)\:\! =\:\! \frac{n}{n+1}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ F(n) - F(n-1) \!\:=\!\: \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Say we want to prove
$$\sum_{r=1}^n f(r)=g(n)$$

Induction can be used to prove this equality by confirming the following two steps:

$f(1)=g(1)$

$g(n+1)-g(n)=f(n+1)$

---

In this case $f(r)=\frac{1}{r(r+1)}$ and $g(n)=\frac{n}{n+1}$.

$f(1)=g(1)=1/2$ so the first step is true.  To check the second step:

$$g(n+1)-g(n)=\frac{n+1}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = f(n+1)$$

The second step is true, thus confirming the equality.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11842/7850) to a question of which *this* question is a duplicate...

Comment: @TheChaz This whole question seems to be a duplicate, you are right.

Comment: @TheChaz And the linked answer is precisely [telescopic induction.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/134925/242)

Answer (score 1):

First show it is true for $n=1$

Then assume it is true up to $n-1$ and show that $$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{r(r+1)} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{n-1}{n}= \frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Note your RHS is $\rm\:\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} + F(n-1) = F(n)\:$ i.e. it's *telescopy*, as in my answer.